# Pass a delegate itself as a parameter

Tags: c#

Is it possible in C# to pass a delegate or event to a method so that the method can assign a new event handler to that delegate with `+=` (and not so that the method can call the delegate)?

Lets say I can mix C++ with C#. This would be what I'm looking for:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public Action* actionPtr;

    public void Assign(Action* action)
    {
        actionPtr = action;
        (*action) += SomeMethod;
    }

    public void Unassign()
    {
        (*action) -= SomeMethod;
    }

    void SomeMethod()
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: It might be better to step back a bit and explain what you are trying to solve here. You question is a little tricky to follow as it stands.

Comment: Never mind I figured it out. I just need to pass it as a ref. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Event: **no** (unless you're in the class where the event is defined). This is enforced by the C# compiler.

Plain old delegate: **yes**. Pass it as a `ref` parameter.

(Think about it this way: how do you add a handler to a delegate? You use `+=`, right? That is an *assignment* operator, which is static: you are assigning the delegate to a new delegate instance that includes the method specified to the right of the `+=`, just like `x += 1` assigns `x` to `x + 1`. The only time you can ever *assign* an external variable to a new value or object from within a method is when it was passed as a `ref` or `out` parameter).

For example, the following code leaves `list` untouched:

```
List<int> list = null;

InitializeListImproperly(list);

static void InitializeListImproperly(List<int> x)
{
    // x is a local variable, so this does nothing to the list variable
    // outside this scope!
    x = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
}
```

The following would assign it to a new `List<int>`:

```
List<int> list = null;

InitializeListProperly(ref list);

static void InitializeListProperly(ref List<int> x)
{
    x = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
}
```

It's the same principle.

Comment: I figured out the pass the delegate as a `ref` thing, but is there also a way to keep a copy of it so that I can later unassign it with `-=`?

Comment: @jsoldi: Keep a copy of what?

Comment: Well, if I assign a new event handler to a delegate with `+=`, I need to unassign it when I'm done right? So if I don't want to unassign it in the same method that receive it as a `ref` parameter, is there any way to unassign it later? As if I would keep a pointer to delegate (not to method to be called by the delegate).

Comment: Just edited my question. Hope it makes more sense.